# Calculating number of total chess games. How to remove invalid positions

Tags: combinatorics, chessboard

While calculating the total number of chess games possible in the universe I used the following approach:

$ \binom{64}{32} $ to select the total number of ways I can arrange 32 pieces on the 64 squared chessboard

$ \binom{32}{16} $ to select 16 places where I can place a specific player's pieces on the board

$ \frac{16!}{8!\cdot(2!)^{3}} $ this gives the ways we can arrange a specific color's pieces in these selected 16 squares. This will also be true for the opponent's peices therefore this result is to be multiplied two times

Hence my final result becomes:

$ \binom{64}{32} \cdot \binom{32}{16} \cdot \frac{16!}{(8!)(2!)^{3}} \cdot\frac{16!}{(8!)(2!)^{3}} $

But this would contain a lot of illegal positions like both kings in check, pawns on the first ranks etc. So how do I remove these posisitons from the extremely large number I have calculated

Comment: Not really related to your question, but how do you have 100 reputation from nothing? And not a single badge?

Comment: its the Association bonus.

Comment: @SkeletonBow That is called the association bonus, and it happens when you link two Stack Exchange accounts together.

Comment: On the other hand, you forgot positions with some pieces captured or converted ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen. If I even include captures how do I do it for odd number of pieces. Take a case where black's pieces are removed and another for white.

Comment: Also, if you are counting only capture-less positions, there are strong restrictions on the pawn postions: There are 15 possibilities to place them per row, resulting in a factor of $15^8$. Then position the remaining 16 pieces on the remaining 32 squares. That's an upper bound of $15^8\cdot{32\choose 16}\cdot\frac{16!}{2!^6}$. Also keep in mind that the two bishops must be on different colours, etc.